# In GeoServer, when adding a layer, how to list all tables when using a "Microsoft SQL Server" store?

Tags: geoserver, sql-server

Presently all the tables are listed when attempting to add a layer from a SQL Server store but the schema is not shown nor used in the definition.  My database has about 3k tables so I'm thinking there is a better way of exploring those tables from GeoServer.  It would be enough if I could use the search tool to find them, but adding them results in a table that cannot be found due to the schema name being missing.

ANSWER: setup a store for each of my schema.

Answer (score 1):

Using schemas to break your tables up is always recommended.

I'm surprised that the SQLServer code doesn't enforce providing a schema or default to something like `public` if you don't provide one as the PostGIS one does. Though to be honest SQLServer never fails to amaze me with it's weirdness.